# Will they make me take off my chest rig bag on takeoff/landing?

Tags: luggage-storage, in-flight-services

There is a new trend of chest bags. They are thin but perhaps I will be required to it take it off and store it overhead?

I don't want to bother wearing one if it's gonna be a hassle.

An example of a chest bag:

[image]

https://ndg-studio.com/collections/accessoires/products/copy-of-escape-chest-pack-black

Comment: Even if they don't, I would not want to wear that or anything like it on landing. If there is an emergency and a landing requiring brace positions is necessary, it could get caught between you and whatever is in front of you, and thereby injure you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yea, and using the same logic, you may not want to use the tray table either. Or put too much heavy stuff in the overhead bins. Contrary to the small pouch, some heavy turbulence (more common that emergencies requiring the brace position) may severely injure you! (or just don't let fear dictate your life ;p)

Comment: @JJJ And that's why you have to lock the tray table up for takeoff and landing. If there's an emergency in cruise, you'll either have plenty of time to stow the tray table before taking the brace position, or if the plane breaks up mid-air, the tray table will be the least of your worries.

Comment: @TooTea I'm not sure if the people who [died of turbulence](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58782/has-turbulence-ever-killed-a-passenger) agree with that. There are many ways to get hurt but the chest bag probably isn't one of them (at least not in the way suggested).

Comment: @JJJ I'm not saying anything about the chest bag, I just wanted to point out that your example with the tray table is not too relevant. I'm also not sure if anyone has ever been killed or seriously hurt by the tray table in turbulence (usually it's just passengers without seatbelts getting thrown about).

Comment: Whatever the answer is, this is just ugly :-) The successor of the fanny pack/bum bag?

Answer (score 2):

**If the cabin crew notices, you'll likely have to take it off.**

It's hard to say for sure without asking the airline in advance. However, most (all?) airlines I've flown ask you to "stow your larger bags into the overhead lockers and smaller items such as handbags under the seat in front of you". I think it's fairly likely that if a cabin attendant sees your (unusual) bag, they'll just err on the side of caution/regulations and ask you to stow it.

Comment: I really don't think it would be an issue. What they want stowed is anything that can move, and thus either hurt someone by being projected onto them, or end up on the floor somewhere where it impedes emergency evacuation. As long as it's attached to the passenger, and is not big enough to be an issue during evacuation (as a backpack could be), it shouldn't really be an issue. This looks pretty thin, probably less than an inch thick?

Answer (score 2):

Probably no worse than a purse, or even a backpack when worn in the front.

I would remove it because it does not look confortable at all when seating in a plane seat for a few hours.

Anyway, you will have to remove it to pass security.

Comment: "Anyway, you will have to remove it to pass security" - this is likely to be some time before boarding a plane. Given it is meant to be worn then chances are you are going to wear it again after security. As an analogy if I have a backpack as my carry on (which I usually do) then its going straight on my back again once I'm through security. I'm not just going to carry it in my hand from there on...